# DataTables Warning: How to solve when submitting form

Tags: html, datatables

I have a scenario like this :

In browser, html page has 6 columns where 6th column holds an icon to copy the corresponding row. Other 5 columns hold data from models. Now, when clicking the icon it's copying the data of the row in a form, but during saving it shows a DataTables Warning. Because we have data only for 5 columns but not for 6th one.

Though, it's showing error,saves the data correctly. But last column showing the button only after page refresh.

I suspect that the POST or form-submission is giving the error but in console it's showing nothing.

Any idea how to solve this dataTables warning issue?

Comment: Not without seeing your relevant code.  The button should work like any other form submission button.

Comment: Also would help to see the console error that it's throwing.

Comment: It's not about the button, it's job is to open the form. That's it. In form there's a save button which saves the data from the row to a new row.Here we are facing problem. Console is not throwing any error.

Comment: If datatables is throwing an error then you should be getting an error in the console...  Anyways, I'll need to see (1) the code that populates the form and (2) the form submission code.  Are you using breakpoints?  Have you been able to narrow it down to a specific section of your POST?